# How to calculate the Lagrangian subgroup of $G\oplus\hat{G}$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, braided-tensor-categories, drinfeld-center

```
Let $G$ be an finite abelian group. We have known the following things:
```

- Denote the Drinfeld center of $\operatorname{Rep}(G)$ by $\mathfrak{Z}_1(\operatorname{Rep}(G))$. We know that the pointed braided fusion category $\mathfrak{Z}_1(\operatorname{Rep}(G))$ can be described by the metric group $(G\oplus\hat{G},q)$ where $\hat{G}$ is dual group of $G$ and $q(g,\rho)=\rho(g)$.
- The Langrangian algebras in $\mathfrak{Z}_1(\operatorname{Rep}(G))$ are classified by a pair $(H,\omega)$ where $H\subset G$ and $\omega\in H^2(H,U(1))$.
- There is a bijection between Lagrangian subgroups of $(G\oplus\hat{G},q)$ and Lagrangian algebras in $\mathfrak{Z}_1(\operatorname{Rep}(G))$.

So my question is

How to calculate the Lagrangian subgroup of $(G\oplus \hat{G},q)$ corresponding the langrangian algebra $(H,\omega)$? I guess that the Lagrangian subgroup of $(G\oplus \hat{G},q)$ corresponding the langrangian algebra $(G,\omega)$ has the form $\{(g,\tau(g,-))\}_{g\in G}$ where $\tau(g,-):=\omega(g,-)\omega^{-1}(-,g)$.